# Is there a method that tells my program to quit?

Tags: python, exit, quit

For the "q" (quit) option in my program menu, I have the following code:

```
elif choice == "q":
    print()
```

That worked all right until I put it in an infinite loop, which kept printing blank lines. Is there a method that can quit the program? Else, can you think of another solution?

Comment: for completness, CTRL-c (KeyboardInterrupt) should be also taken into account

Answer (score 98, accepted):

One way is to do:

```
sys.exit(0)
```

You will have to `import sys` of course.

Another way is to `break` out of your infinite loop. For example, you could do this:

```
while True:
    choice = get_input()
    if choice == "a":
        # do something
    elif choice == "q":
        break
```

Yet another way is to put your main loop in a function, and use `return`:

```
def run():
    while True:
        choice = get_input()
        if choice == "a":
            # do something
        elif choice == "q":
            return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

The only reason you need the `run()` function when using `return` is that (unlike some other languages) you can't directly `return` from the main part of your Python code (the part that's not inside a function).

Comment: For the sake of completeness: `raise SystemExit` would also work on its own (although not advised).

Comment: @ChristopheD: I chose to omit discussion of exceptions, since they should not be used for normal program flow.

Comment: exceptions are not that exceptional in Python.

Answer (score 26):

The actual way to end a program, is to call

```
raise SystemExit
```

It's what `sys.exit` [does, anyway](http://docs.python.org/library/exceptions.html#SystemExit).

A plain `SystemExit`, or with `None` as a single argument, sets the process' exit code to zero. Any non-integer exception value (`raise SystemExit("some message")`) prints the exception value to `sys.stderr` and sets the exit code to 1. An integer value sets the process' exit code to the value:

```
$ python -c "raise SystemExit(4)"; echo $?
4
```

Answer (score 14):

In Python 3 there is an `exit()` function:

```
elif choice == "q":
    exit()
```

Comment: I don't see that one in [Built-in Functions](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html) - perhaps you're thinking of the one in [`sys`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/sys.html)?

Comment: I don't see it either, but it does appear to work for me (Python 2.6)

Comment: That's actually a concession for the interpreter mode - try `print(exit)` and see what you get. `quit` is similar.

Comment: Both exit() and quit() seem to quit it in IDLE.

P.S. How do you put stuff as code (i.e. functions) in comments?

Comment: `exit()` [is added by the `site` package](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/constants.html?highlight=exit#constants-added-by-the-site-module). The documentation says it shouldn't be used in programs :$

Comment: (@Greg: being in the `site` module means that it is not exclusive to the interactive interpreter)

Answer (score 3):

See [`sys.exit`](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.exit). That function will quit your program with the given exit status.

Answer (score 3):

Please note that the solutions based on sys.exit() or any Exception may not work in a multi-threaded environment.

> Since exit() ultimately “only” raises an exception, it will only exit the process when called from the main thread, and the exception is not intercepted. ([doc](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/sys.html#sys.exit))

[This answer from Alex Martelli](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1635084/777285) for more details.