# exit script command in Python

Tags: string, python-3.x, exit

To start off I'm new to coding.
To practice basic strings and commands I'm making a little decision-based game, you know the classic left or right type thing. The problem is that I do not know an exit command. I have it written to where if you make certain choices you die and when you die i want to have it written to where the script boots you. sort of like

```
print('You have died..exit?')

user_choice = input('Okay')

if user_choice == 'Okay':

(here is where i would put the exit code)

else:

(Exit code again...no getting out of it)
```

Please help! I litterally just started coding today...>.<

Answer (score 0):

well to just close a program you can

```
import sys
```

and then wherever you want:

```
sys.exit(0)
```

[Is there a method that tells my program to quit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2823472/is-there-a-method-that-tells-my-program-to-quit)