# Best way to quit a python programme?

Tags: python, exit

I feel like an idiot asking this but is doing `quit()` the best way to terminate a python programme? Or is there a better way that could gradually stop all while True loops ect instead of just instantly stopping it all? Once again, I feel like an idiot asking this but I'm just curious.

Comment: Do you have created any resources/opened files, etc.?

Comment: In this case, it's reading a text file.

Comment: @Charlie what do you mean by "gradually stop all while True loops". Please elaborate.

Comment: @BOi I don't know, I'm 13 and still an idiot when it comes to coding. I'm just trying to learn as much as possible.

Comment: posible duplicate of [Is there a method that tells my program to quit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2823472/is-there-a-method-that-tells-my-program-to-quit)

Comment: well @Charlie welcome to coding. You're not an idiot if you're trying to learn. I just wanted you to clarify your question so I can help you with exactly what you want..

Comment: @BOi Thanks, and I don't really know what I meant. I just didn't know if it's possible that if you terminate a while True loop if it could possibly result in some unwanted behaviour such as maybe it stopped reading in the middle of a string thus making text have printed or something like that. I really don't know.

Comment: @Charlie nothing of that sort happens. When quit() is placed somewhere in your code, the program will just stop no matter what is happening. It won't do anything else.

Comment: @Charlie if my answer helped please press the check mark next to it to accept it.

Comment: @BOi I would but I cannot find a check mark. Could it possibly be because I have only 6 reputation because that has stopped my doing some other things?

Comment: @Charlie https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkiIZ.png try this.

Comment: Oh okay sorry, I was looking else-where

Comment: @Charlie that is absolutely no problem. Thanks a lot and good luck with whatever you are trying to make.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know why you don't want to use `quit()` but you can use this:

```
import sys
sys.exit()
```

Or this:

```
raise SystemExit(0)
```

To halt a while loop you can use the `break` statement. For example:

```
while True:
    if True:
        do something  #pseudocode
    else:
        break
```

The `break` statement will immediately halt the `while` loop as soon as the `else` statement is read by python

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `break` statement to stop a while loop. Eg:

```
while True:
    if True:
        <do something>
    else:
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally, the best way to end a Python program is just to let the code run to completion. For example, a script that looks for "hello" in a file could look like this:

```
# import whatever other modules you want to use
import some_module

# define functions you will use
def check_file(filename, phrase):
    with open filename as f:
        while True:
            # using a while loop, but you might prefer a for loop
            line = f.readline()
            if not f:
                # got to end of file without finding anything
                found = False
                break
            elif phrase in line:
                found = True
                break
    # note: the break commands will exit the loop, then the function will return
    return found

# define the code to run if you call this script on its own
# rather than importing it as a module
if __name__ == '__main__':
    if check_file("myfile.txt", "hello"):
        print("found 'hello' in myfile.txt")
    else:
        print("'hello' is not in myfile.txt")

# there's no more code to run here, so the script will end
# -- no need to call quit() or sys.exit()
```

Note that once the phrase is found or the search comes to the end of the file, the code will break out of the loop, and then the rest of the script will run. Eventually, the script will run out of code to run, and Python will exit or return to the interactive command line.

Comment: I believe that the OP wants to terminate the program using his commands. I'm pretty sure he knows that letting a program run to completion will end the program soon.

Comment: Thank you for going out of your way to post this but I already knew that allowing the programme to run to completion will eventually make it stop. But again thanks.

Comment: At the top where it says `def check_file(filename, phrase):` what does "phrase" mean?

Comment: @Charlie, the "phrase" variable just holds the text that you're searching for in the file. It could just as well be called "word" or "text." By the way, if you must exit directly from the deep inside the program, the best option is probably to raise an exception (possibly SystemExit). This won't do any harm if you don't have any important unsaved data or unfinished work. It will just end your program (and the computer won't mind if it's in the middle of a loop).

Comment: @BOi the point I was making is that you almost always can (and should) arrange your code so it runs to the end under normal circumstances. So if the question is, "what's the best way to exit a Python program even if it's in a loop?" then the answer is "setup the logic so your program ends when the job is done."

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stop a `while True` loop, you could set a variable to True and False, you could even work with a counter if you loop has to stop after a specific amount of loops.

for example

```
x = 0
y = True
while y == True:
    <do something>
    x = x + 1
    if x == 9:
        y = False
```

just a quick example of what you could do, without using a while loop(basically what i wrote above, but then in 1 line.)

```
x = 10
for i in range(x):
    <do something>
```

To stop a program, I normally use `exit()` or `break`.

I hope this somehow helped you, if not; please comment and I'll try helping you!

Comment: Hey, I don't really understand the second section of code that you sent. 

`x = 10
for i in range(x):
    <do something>`

Where does the letter `i` come from, or is that just a place holder?

Comment: `i` is the variable that's being created, it is indeed a placeholder, you could also write `for charlies in range(x):`. Try it out by typing `for charlies in range(x): print(charlies)`. It will output a counter from 0 till 9 (python starts counting at 0 instead of 1)

Comment: exactly what @DevOps said. It creates a variable called i that can be used to iterate through the range of x.

Comment: anytime! Keep learning and remember, we all started where you started!