# Detect failed tasks in concurrent.futures

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, python-multithreading, concurrent.futures

I've been using concurrent.futures as it has a simple interface and let user easily control the max number of threads/processes. However, it seems like concurrent.futures hides failed tasks and continue the main thread after all tasks finished/failed.

```
import concurrent.futures

def f(i):
    return (i + 's')

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
    fs = [executor.submit(f, i ) for i in range(10)]
    concurrent.futures.wait(fs)
```

Calling f on any integer leads an TypeError. However, the whole script runs just fine and exits with code 0. Is there any way to make it throw an exception/error when any thread failed?

Or, is there a better way to limit number of threads/processes without using concurrent.futures?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33448329/how-to-detect-exceptions-in-concurrent-futures-in-python3

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`concurrent.futures.wait` will ensure all the tasks completed, but it doesn't check success (something `return`-ed) vs. failure (exception raised and not caught in worker function). To do that, you need to call [`.result()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Future.result) on each `Future` (which will cause it to either re-`raise` the exception from the task, or produce the `return`-ed value). There are other methods to check without actually raising in the main thread (e.g. `.exception()`), but `.result()` is the most straightforward method.

If you want to make it re-`raise`, the simplest approach is just to replace the `wait()` call with:

```
for fut in concurrent.futures.as_completed(fs):
    fut.result()
```

which will process results as `Future`s complete, and promptly `raise` an `Exception` if one occurred. Alternatively, you continue to use `wait` so all tasks finish before you check for exceptions on any of them, then iterate over `fs` directly and call `.result()` on each.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to do the same with multiprocessing.Pool (for processes) or multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool (for threads). As far as I know it rethrows any caught exceptions.

Comment: This question is about `concurrent.futures` AFAIK this is the more modern implementation of the multiprocessing module. For me it makes no sense to suggest to use the old library.

Comment: @guettli, this old library is still actively used by many parallel libraries, e.g. Joblib and Dask. And futures are just functionally not equivalent to Pool with its `map` function - which is potentially more efficient than waiting on multiple future objects.

Comment: Yes, multiprocessing is actively used by many libraries. But the heading of this question is: "Detect failed tasks in concurrent.futures"

Comment: Yes. But does it mean we cannot suggest any alternatives to the way OP thinks? Sometimes there is no other way to anwer the question but redirect to something else.

Comment: AFAIK concurrent.futures is more modern. I know multiprocessing is not deprecated, but I would not suggest to go back. Of course redirecting to something else is very helpful sometimes.