# Simplest way to timeout a Python function on Windows

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading, python-decorators

The following process runs for ten seconds. I want to kill it after five seconds.

```
import time

def hello():
    for _ in range(10):
        print("hello")
        time.sleep(1)

hello()
```

The solution could involve threads, multiprocessing or decorators. Similar questions have been asked before (sorry in advance), but the solutions have all been highly complex. Something as basic-sounding as this should be achievable with just a few lines of code.

Comment: Does it have to be windows? For example, if you run the script in docker or cygwin, then you'd be able to use [signal.alarm](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html#signal.alarm) which is only available on Unix platforms.

Comment: I'm using Windows unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

depends on use case ... for this very specific example

```
import time

def hello(timeout=5):
    start_time = time.time()
    for _ in range(10):
        if time.time()-start_time > timeout:
           break
        print("hello")
        time.sleep(1)

hello()
```

is one way you could do it

alternatively you could use multiprocessing

```
import multiprocessing
...
if __name__ == "__main__":
  proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=hello)
  proc.start()
  time.sleep(5)
  proc.terminate()
```

Comment: Joran, thanks so much for the response. But your solution is generating the following: "RuntimeError: 
            Attempt to start a new process before the current process
            has finished its bootstrapping phase.

            This probably means that you are on Windows and you have
            forgotten to use the proper idiom in the main module:"

Comment: @NedHulton did you guard creating the process inside `if __name__ == "__main__"`?

Comment: just put the proc stuff behind an `if __name__ == "__main__":`   (edited example)

Comment: also if you are going to bundle it into an exe you may have to add as the first line inside the main guard  `multiprocessing.freeze_support()` since windows handles forking/spawning quite differrently than linux

Comment: Just added the if __name__ == "__main__":  line now. Seems to work. Thanks.

Comment: Quick question: How do I determine if the "hello" function is still running?

Comment: you can use `proc.poll()` if it returns None it is still running

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [`multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool). This will work both on Windows and Linux.

### Basic solution

```py
import multiprocessing.pool

try:
    with multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool() as pool:
        pool.apply_async(hello).get(timeout=5)
except multiprocessing.TimeoutError:
    # do something if timeout
```

This will run `hello` in a separate thread. If `hello` has not terminated after 5 seconds, the separate thread is killed.

- `get` will raise `multiprocessing.TimeoutError` if the separate thread has not completed after `timeout` seconds.
- This will immediately kill the separate thread :

  - Exiting the `with` block triggers the execution of `pool.__exit__()`
  - I did not find in the documentation an explanation about what `pool.__exit__()` does, but we can see in [its source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.11/Lib/multiprocessing/pool.py) that it calls `pool.terminate()`
  - According to [its documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.terminate), `pool.terminate()` "*stops the worker processes immediately without completing outstanding work.*". (Note that the documentation talks about worker *processes* here because it is the documentation for `multiprocessing.pool.Pool`, which uses processes. `ThreadPool` provides the same API as `Pool` but uses threads.)

### Arguments

You can pass arguments to your function :

```py
try:
    with multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool() as pool:
        pool.apply_async(
            hello,
            (positional_argument, other_positional_argument),
            {keyword_argument=42, other_keyword_argument=1337}
        ).get(timeout=5)
except multiprocessing.TimeoutError:
    # do something if timeout
```

### Return value

You can get the return value of your function :

```py
try:
    with multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool() as pool:
        return_value = pool.apply_async(hello).get(timeout=5)
except multiprocessing.TimeoutError:
    # do something if timeout
else:
    # do something with return_value
```

### Exceptions

If your function raises an exception, it will be transparently reraised :

```py
try:
    with multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool() as pool:
        pool.apply_async(hello).get(timeout=5)
except multiprocessing.TimeoutError:
    # do something if timeout
except SomeExceptionRaisedByHello as e:
    # do something with e
```

### Use a process instead of a thread

If you want to run your function in a separate process instead of a separate thread, just use [`multiprocessing.pool.Pool`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool). It has the same API as [`multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool).

Note that in this case you have to use `if __name__ == '__main__'` :

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        with multiprocessing.pool.Pool() as pool:
            pool.apply_async(hello)
    except multiprocessing.TimeoutError:
        # do something if timeout
```

### Note about `concurrent.futures.Executor`

The documentation stays the following about [`ThreadPool`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool) :

> Users should generally prefer to use concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor, which has a simpler interface that was designed around threads from the start, and which returns concurrent.futures.Future instances that are compatible with many other libraries, including asyncio.

[`concurrent.futures`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) has an `Executor` class that offers similar functionality to `multiprocessing`'s pools. However using an `Executor` instances to timeout a function like we did with `multiprocessing`'s pool poses the following problem :

With an `Executor`, it is impossible to kill the separate thread or process when the timeout occurs (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29177490/how-do-you-kill-futures-once-they-have-started)). You can wait on your separate thread or process until a timeout occurs and then continue the execution of your main program, but the separate thread or process will still run in parallel until the target function terminates.

This is especially problematic if the function you want to timeout may never terminate or may take a very long time to do so, because its execution will continue even if your main program terminates. In this scenario, instead of terminating, your python scrip will hang for ever at the end of its execution waiting on the separate thread or process executing your target function.