# Immediately raise exceptions in concurrent.futures

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency

I run several threads concurrently using `concurrent.futures`. All of them are necessary to run successfully for the next steps in the code to succeed.

While at the end of all processes I can raise any exceptions by running `.result()`, ideally any exception raised in a single thread would immediately stop all threads. This would be helpful to identify bugs in any task sooner, rather than waiting until all long-running processes complete.

Is this possible?

Comment: Can you not wrap your task function (or functions) with a `try:..except:..` that signals the other tasks to abort?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand @SolomonSlow -- how would you signal all the other tasks to abort?

Comment: I probably would have each of the tasks periodically test a global boolean variable or a field in a mutable, shared object with a name like `abort`, and I would have them stop whatever they were doing and exit if `abort` became `True`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to exit after the first exception and not submit any new jobs to the Executor. However, once a job has been submitted, it can't be cancelled, you have to wait for all submitted jobs to finish (or timeout). See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42782953/python-concurrent-futures-how-to-make-it-cancelable) for details. Here's a short example that cancels any unsubmitted jobs once the first exception occurs. However, it still waits for the already submitted jobs to finish. This uses the `FIRST_EXCEPTION` constant listed in the [concurrent.futures `wait(return_when=...)` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.wait).

```
import time
import concurrent.futures

def example(i):
    print(i)
    assert i != 1
    time.sleep(i)
    return i

if __name__ == "__main__":
    futures = []
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        for number in range(5):
            futures.append(executor.submit(example, number))

        exception = False
        for completed, running_or_error in concurrent.futures.wait(futures, return_when="FIRST_EXCEPTION"):
            try:
                 running_or_error.result()
            except Exception as e:
                for future in futures:
                    print(future.cancel()) # cancel all unstarted futures
                raise e
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with the argument used by [answer by SNygard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71073824/5861244) as I explain in the old reply below. One can do something like the following (the outer most `try-except` and the time `print()` statements are for illustrations):

```py
import concurrent.futures
import os
import time


def job(i):
    print(f"Job {i} started")
    if i == 1:
        raise ValueError(i)
    time.sleep(10)
    print(f"Job {i} finished")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    start = time.time()
    pool = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(2)
    try:
        try:
            print(f"Submitting tasks at {time.time() - start}")
            tasks = [pool.submit(job, i) for i in range(6)]
            done_tasks, not_done_tasks = concurrent.futures.wait(tasks, return_when=concurrent.futures.FIRST_EXCEPTION)
            for task in done_tasks:
                err = task.exception()
                if err is not None:
                    print(f"Raising at {time.time() - start}")
                    raise RuntimeError from err
        finally:
            print(f"Shutting down pool at {time.time() - start}")
            pool.shutdown(wait=False, cancel_futures=True)
    except RuntimeError:
        print(f"Caught exception at {time.time() - start}")
        raise
```

which gives something like:

```py
Submitting tasks at 0.0014691352844238281
Job 0 started
Job 1 started
Job 2 started
Raising at 0.0017800331115722656
Shutting down pool at 0.0017862319946289062
Caught exception at 0.0017962455749511719
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path/to/python3.11/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 58, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "path/to/file.py", line 9, in job
    raise ValueError(i)
ValueError: 1

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path/to/file.py", line 26, in <module>
    raise RuntimeError from err
RuntimeError
Job 0 finished
Job 2 finished
```

As pointed out by https://stackoverflow.com/users/4691830/joooeey, we still wait for the child threads to finish (but the main thread is done and tasks that were not started got cancelled). To stop the running threads, then you are looking at a problem like at [How do you kill Futures once they have started?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29177490/how-do-you-kill-futures-once-they-have-started) which does not seem to have a nice solution if you use `concurrent.futures` (e.g. adding a global flag to check requires changing the implementation of the function being run).

---

## Former reply

I saw the [answer by SNygard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71073824/5861244). The future with the exception seems to be in the completed task and not the still running tasks. Take

```py
import concurrent.futures
import time


def job(i):
    if i == 1:
        raise ValueError(i)

    print(f"Job {i} started")
    time.sleep(2)
    print(f"Job {i} finished")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(2) as pool:
        start = time.time()
        tasks = [pool.submit(job, i) for i in range(6)]
        done_tasks, not_done_tasks = concurrent.futures.wait(tasks, return_when=concurrent.futures.FIRST_EXCEPTION)
        for task in done_tasks:
            err = task.exception()
            if err is not None:
                n_cancelled = 0
                for not_done in not_done_tasks:
                    n_cancelled += 1
                    print(f"Cancelling {n_cancelled} at {time.time() - start}")
                    not_done.cancel()
                print(f"Raising at {time.time() - start}")
                raise RuntimeError from err
```

Running this gives something like

```
Job 0 started
Cancelling 1 at 0.00018787384033203125
Job 2 started
Cancelling 2 at 0.00021409988403320312
Cancelling 3 at 0.0002319812774658203
Cancelling 4 at 0.00023603439331054688
Cancelling 5 at 0.0002391338348388672
Raising at 0.00024199485778808594
Job 0 finished
Job 2 finished
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path/to/python3.11/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 58, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "path/to/file.py", line 7, in job
    raise ValueError(i)
ValueError: 1

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path/to/file.py", line 28, in <module>
    raise RuntimeError from err
RuntimeError
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The threads are only stopped after ten (5*2) seconds, not immediately as requested.

Comment: Thank you. I forgot to cancel the other tasks. That is done now.

Comment: It still doesn't work. `.cancel` doesn't stop running tasks as per the docs. Use `time.sleep(10)` and see what happens.

Comment: You are correct. But it stops task 3-5 to start in this case (see the updated answer). My main point is that the solution at https://stackoverflow.com/a/71073824/5861244 got it wrong (looks for the exception in the wrong returned element). As grey_ranger points out, if this is correct https://stackoverflow.com/a/45565421/5861244, then you cannot stop the running futures from `concurrent.futures`.

Comment: It seems likes one just waits for the child processes to finish (see the new answer). I guess one can kill them as suggested by https://stackoverflow.com/a/45515052/5861244.

Comment: That link is about multiprocessing – it doesn’t apply to multithreading.

Comment: Thanks again. I updated the answer to reflect this.